# Call razor from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

I have a radio button as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Select address" onclick="selectAddress(@item.Id)" />
```

Then, the following javascript:

```
            <script>
                $(function () {


                    function selectAddress(selectedId) {
                        if ($('#TermsAccepted').is(':checked')) {
                            setLocation('@Url.RouteUrl("SelectCustomerAddress", new { addressId = selectedId})')
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#checkErrorMsg').toggle();
                        }  
                    }
                })
            </script>
```

The problem is that the code has a syntax error because selectedId is not know due to mixing razor and javascript. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `selectAddress` is defined as a local function and won't fire by the click event of the input. Use `window.selectAddress = function (selectedId) {}` instead.

Comment: You need to put this method outside the $(function(){}), Skilwz's answer will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your URL in javascript and not Razor:

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    function selectAddress(selectedId) {
      if ($('#TermsAccepted').is(':checked')) {
        setLocation(
          '@Url.RouteUrl("SelectCustomerAddress")?addressId='+selectedId);
      }
      else {
        $('#checkErrorMsg').toggle();
      }  
    }
  })
</script>
```